# How to use LuaJIT the same that Lua in a C++ program?

Tags: lua

I'm using **Lua** in my **C++** program, as an library. But I read that **LuaJIT** is a better implementation.

Is it posible to replace with **LuaJIT** with little change? How?

Comment: Just replace the source files if you're compiling from source, or the DLL if you're using the precompiled one. LuaJIT is meant to be a drop-in replacement for stock lua, so it should work just by replacing it.

Comment: @PandaPajama that should probably be an answer, not a comment

Comment: It's not so simple on Mac OS X

Comment: Here's a relevant [email discussion](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2013-01/msg00554.html) about the pros/cons of various Lua implementations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just replace the source files if you're compiling from source, or the DLL if you're using the precompiled one (preferred).

Per the [Installation Guide](http://luajit.org/install.html):

> LuaJIT is API-compatible with Lua 5.1. If you've already embedded Lua
>   into your application, you probably don't need to do anything to
>   switch to LuaJIT, except link with a different library:

LuaJIT is meant to be a drop-in replacement for stock lua, so it should work just by replacing it

Answer (score 2):

As **Panda Pajama** comment suggest. It's easy a drop-in replacement.

- Change include path to get LuaJIT lua.hpp file
- Downgrade code from Lua 5.2 API to Lua 5.1 API.
- Linked with LuaJIT library instead of lua library

The worst part was the downgrade to 5.1, specially the load of own function modules in lua State.